# How to render YUV data by using DirectX11 or DirectX12

Tags: c++, wpf, directx, directx-11, directx-12

I have a C++ dll project where YUV data has been processed by using directX9 in an IDirect3DSurface9. Then this surface has been passed to the WPF side by a callback function to render it from WPF side by using D3DImage. But rendering FPS is very slow, near around or below 30 FPS. But we are expecting 50~60 FPS.

```
  ComPtr<IDirect3D9Ex>           m_pD3D9Ex; 
  ComPtr<IDirect3DDevice9Ex>     m_pDeviceEx; 
  ComPtr<IDirect3DSurface9>      m_pDirect3DSurfaceRender;
  ComPtr<IDirect3DSurface9>      m_pTargetSurface; 
  ComPtr<IDirect3DTexture9>      m_pTexture; 
  ComPtr<IDirect3DVertexBuffer9> m_pVertexBuffer; 
  ComPtr<IDirect3DVertexShader9> m_pVertexShader; 
  ComPtr<ID3DXConstantTable>     m_pVertexConstantTable;    
  ComPtr<ID3DXConstantTable>     m_pPixelConstantTable;
  ComPtr<IDirect3DPixelShader9>  m_pPixelShader; 
  
    
  RESULT MyDirect3D9::Render(BYTE* pYplane, BYTE* pUplane, BYTE* pVplane)
  {
     HRESULT lRet;
  
     //Necessary Checkings for buffer and other stuff
  
     // fill buffer
    if(m_pDirect3DSurfaceRender == NULL)
        return -1;
    D3DLOCKED_RECT d3d_rect;
    lRet=m_pDirect3DSurfaceRender->LockRect(&d3d_rect,NULL,D3DLOCK_DONOTWAIT);
    if(FAILED(lRet))
        return -1;
  
    int newHeight  = m_videoHeight;
     int newWidth  = m_videoWidth;
  
     BYTE* pict = (BYTE*)d3drect.pBits;
     BYTE* Y = pY;
     BYTE* V = pV;
     BYTE* U = pU;
  
    //Copy D3DFMT_YV12 Data
    for (int y = 0 ; y < newHeight ; y++)
     {
         memcpy(pict, Y, newWidth);
         pict += d3drect.Pitch;
         Y += newWidth;
     }
     for (int y = 0 ; y < newHeight >> 1; y++)
     {
         memcpy(pict, V, newWidth >> 1);
         pict += d3drect.Pitch >> 1;
         V += newWidth >> 1;
     }
     for (int y = 0 ; y < newHeight >> 1; y++)
     {
         memcpy(pict, U, newWidth >> 1);
         pict += d3drect.Pitch >> 1;
         U += newWidth >> 1;
     }  
  
    lRet=m_pDirect3DSurfaceRender->UnlockRect();
    if(FAILED(lRet))
        return -1;
    
     // create scene
    if (m_pDirect3DDevice == NULL)
        return -1;
    
    //All kinds of HR check has been performed. For code simplicity, detail code has not been mensioned.
     lRet = m_pDirect3DDevice->Clear(D3DADAPTER_DEFAULT, NULL, D3DCLEAR_TARGET, D3DCOLOR_XRGB(0, 0, 0), 1.0f, 0);
     lRet = m_pDirect3DDevice->BeginScene();
     lRet = m_pDirect3DDevice->SetFVF(D3DFVF_CUSTOMVERTEX);
     lRet = m_pDirect3DDevice->SetVertexShader(m_pVertexShader);
     lRet = m_pDirect3DDevice->SetPixelShader(m_pPixelShader);
     lRet = m_pDirect3DDevice->SetStreamSource(0, m_pVertexBuffer, 0, sizeof(VERTEX));
     lRet = m_pDirect3DDevice->SetTexture(0, m_pTexture);
     lRet = m_pDirect3DDevice->DrawPrimitive(D3DPT_TRIANGLEFAN, 0, 2);
    
     m_overlays.Draw();
     m_pDirect3DDevice->EndScene();
    
    //IDirect3DSurface9 * pBackBuffer = NULL;
    //m_pDirect3DDevice->GetBackBuffer(0,0,D3DBACKBUFFER_TYPE_MONO,&pBackBuffer);
    //m_pDirect3DDevice->StretchRect(m_pDirect3DSurfaceRender,NULL,pBackBuffer,&m_rtViewport,D3DTEXF_LINEAR);
    //m_pDirect3DDevice->EndScene();
    //m_pDirect3DDevice->Present( NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL );
    //pBackBuffer->Release();
    
    // present 
     lRet = m_pDirect3DDevice->ColorFill(m_pTargetSurface, NULL, D3DCOLOR_ARGB(0xFF, 0, 0, 0));
    lRet = m_pDirect3DDevice->StretchRect(m_pDirect3DSurfaceRender, NULL, m_pTargetSurface, NULL, D3DTEXF_LINEAR);
    lRet = m_pDirect3DDevice->Present( NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL );
     
    return lRet;
   }
```

Here below is the WPF side D3DImage render:

```
     //WPF side code
 public void OnRender(IntPtr pSurface) 
 {
     if (d3dimg.IsFrontBufferAvailable)
     {
         if (pSurface != IntPtr.Zero)
         {
             PrintFPS();

             d3dimg.Lock();
             d3dimg.SetBackBuffer(D3DResourceType.IDirect3DSurface9, pSurface);
             d3dimg.AddDirtyRect(new Int32Rect(0, 0, d3dimg.PixelWidth, d3dimg.PixelHeight));
             d3dimg.Unlock();
         }
     }
 }
```

[Intel showed up how using DirectX 12 can all to a 70% improvement in performance as well as using 50% less power](https://software.intel.com/content/www/us/en/develop/blogs/siggraph-2014-directx-12-on-intel.html).

Now I want to process/render YUV data by using DirectX11/DirectX12. The rendering process seems very different from DirectX9 to DirectX11/DirectX12.

Any kind of help will be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Update:
Be more concrete: To perform DirectX9 render we follow the below procedure:

1. Copy YUV buffer to a byte pointer using IDirect3DSurface9
2. Create IDirect3DDevice9 device such as m_pDirect3DDevice.
3. Perform m_pDirect3DDevice->Clear
4. m_pDirect3DDevice->BeginScene()
5. Get back buffer: m_pDirect3DDevice->GetBackBuffer(...)
6. Then StretchRect to the predefined surface. m_pDirect3DDevice->StretchRect(....)
7. Finally perform EndScene & Present(...)

I want to know the basic rendering procedure for DirectX11 or DirectX12

I have checked out below link below but still unable to find any fruitful observation for YUV data rendering.

[WPFDXInterop](https://github.com/Microsoft/WPFDXInterop/blob/master/samples/D3D11Image/WpfD3D11Interop/MainWindow.xaml.cs) , [WPF DirectX Extensions](https://github.com/microsoft/WPFDXInterop), [GPUOpen Libraries & SDKs](https://github.com/GPUOpen-LibrariesAndSDKs/HelloD3D12/)

Comment: WPF's D3DImage only supports DirectX9 https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.interop.d3dresourcetype there have been some attempt to use DirectX11 with WPF: http://jmorrill.hjtcentral.com/Home/tabid/428/EntryId/437/Direct3D-10-11-Direct2D-in-WPF.aspx https://github.com/microsoft/WPFDXInterop